# Mysterious Word files!

Tags: file-sharing, files, microsoft-office

I have a a simple file share server, which all my users use. After 3 years some has decided to tell IT that some strange files exist in the folder structure.

They appear to be opened Word files but it seems highly unlikely that every file is open. It appears that all the files in question are word files of existing word files with ~$A-08_ at the start of the filename followed by an existing filename.

When I try to open the files it needs to be converted but it doesn't display anything??????

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I'm not certain exactly what the behavior of these files are, the are like temp files that word creates when a user is editing a document (I'd assume similar to VI's file.ext.swp).  The reason why they're still there is that word terminated improperly, or the client lost connection when editing a file on a share.

Comment: +1. Right on the money. @stead1984: These files are useless and unneeded. Simply delete them.

Comment: Exactly the case.  Often left behind when Word closes unexpectedly